# get an array with a predefined structure using preg_match or preg_match_all

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match, preg-match-all

Here is an example string:

**"60 reviews from 12 people, 20% of users"**
(Let's call it $v)

I have been using preg_match_all to get an array with all the numbers

```
$pattern = '!\d+!';
preg_match_all($pattern, $v, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The result I get is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 60
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
        )
)
```

But despite trying for some time I haven't been able to get what I want. **What I want is this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 60
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 20
)
```

Maybe should I be using preg_match instead? but with preg_match I only get one value... Or maybe along with a loop? It looks like an ugly hack... There should be a profesional way out there... Thanks in advance to PHP experts! ;)

Comment: Remove "PREG_SET_ORDER", and you will get almost what you want. $matches[0] will be your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming the format always stays the same, you can do the following:

```
<?php

    // Input string/line
    $v = "60 reviews from 12 people, 20% of users";

    // Match regex (0-9; min 1 or max unlimited numbers)
    preg_match_all("/[0-9]{1,}/", $v, $matches);

    // Remove/sub key
    $matches = $matches[0];

    // Echo out
    print_r($matches);

?>
```

This will output:

```
 Array ( 
       [0] => 60     // < Access using $matches[0]
       [1] => 12     // < Access using $matches[1]
       [2] => 20     // < Access using $matches[2]
 )
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it worked, but I'm afraid the format will change and will never be the same

Comment: You're welcome. Then in time, you'll need a more sophisticated regex to deal with 'reviews', 'people' and 'of users' if it doesn't stay the same or the format changes. It's not a complex regex though! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you want?, array_values($array)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)